# Travis-CI failing to build due to PySide2 and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6, travis-ci, pyside2

I have a github repository where I develop an [electrical calculation software](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal).

Recently I completely migrated from PyQt5 to PySide2.

Today I added Travis-CI for continuous integration as a hook to the Githb repository. This means that when I push some changes, travis-CI launches a build of my repository in an independent machine in their cloud.

Travis CI is failing due to this:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/travis/build/SanPen/GridCal/src/tests/test_branch_tolerance.py'. Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names. Traceback: src/tests/test_branch_tolerance.py:1: in <module>
    from GridCal.Engine import * src/GridCal/Engine/__init__.py:17: in <module>
    from GridCal.Engine.basic_structures import * src/GridCal/Engine/basic_structures.py:23: in <module>
    from GridCal.Engine.plot_config import LINEWIDTH, plt src/GridCal/Engine/plot_config.py:18: in <module>
    matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg') ../../../virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py:307: in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs) ../../../virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1297: in use
    switch_backend(name) ../../../virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:230: in switch_backend
    newbackend, required_framework, current_framework)) 

E   ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

The failing file `plot_config.py` has the following matplotlib configuration at the beginning:

```
import PySide2  # this line is necessary so that Matplotlib recognises that PySide is the Qt Backend
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
# matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5'] = 'PySide2'  # this is not supported anymore
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

This code is what I've found on several threads to be the right thing to do. However the automated tests on an independent machine fail because of them.

**So, What is the best and unambiguous way to tell matplotlib to use PySide2?**

The packages required are (requirements.txt):

```
PySide2>=5.11 
numpy>=1.14.0 
scipy>=1.0.0 
networkx>=2.1 
pandas>=0.22 
xlwt>=1.3.0 
xlrd>=1.1.0 
matplotlib>=3.1.0 
qtconsole>=4.3.1 
pyDOE>=0.3.8 
pySOT>=0.2.1 
openpyxl>=2.4.9 
pulp>=1.6.8 
smopy>=0.0.6 
chardet>=3.0.4 
scikit-learn>=0.18 
geopy>=1.16 
pytest>=3.8 
h5py>=2.9.0
```

Comment: What are you using pyplot for? The project looks like it's entirely embedding matplotlib into the PySide GUI?

Comment: `plt` is used in the file to set the default style. Focus on the backend stuff.

Comment: Yeah, so the error is only there because you import pyplot, which seemed not necessary. You also don't need pyplot to set any default style. So there are really two separate things here, one is to get your repo running, the other is how to set the backend to use pyside2 when using pyplot.

Comment: The file is this https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/src/GridCal/Engine/plot_config.py

Comment: For that matter you can use `matplotlib.style` instead of `pyplot.style` and `matplotlib.rc` instead of `pyplot.rc`.

Comment: The trace indicates that the failure is at `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`

Comment: will try as you say

Comment: I'm not saying that there isn't any bug or so somewhere, but your actual problem would be circumvented by not using pyplot. If you do not use pyplot, you do not need to set any backend, and the `matplotlib.use` line can be removed.

Comment: Still fails: `ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running`. The origin is the same `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')`

Comment: You're probably right. So far I run the tests on a clean python distro, and the tests pass. Anyway a better way to force PySide2 as matplotlib backend is needed

Comment: I said, remove the line `matplotlib.use`. My point is, you don't want to set any backend in the sense of `.use`. This is only needed for pyplot, but using pyplot is contradictory to embedding matplotlib in a custom GUI. This would then not only prevent those test failures, but also prevent problems with users who might have already set a different backend at any point prior to starting your software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enable the XVFB service as indicated in the [docs](https://benlimmer.com/2019/01/14/travis-ci-xvfb/) to be able to test libraries that need a graphical environment:

```
dist: xenial   # required for Python >= 3.7
services:
  - xvfb
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
# command to run tests
script:
  - pytest
```

I have created a [PR](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/pull/101) to your repository.